# get the size of QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to do the following:

1. create a QGraphicsView
2. connect it to QGraphicsScene
3. Get the size of the QGraphicsScene
4. create a QGraphicsRectItem with this size

My problem is how to get the size of the scene
In all the examples I saw that they put constants in setSceneRect()
The following is my code

```
class CharIdentifierInput(QDialog, Ui_CharIdentifierInput):
    """description of class"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.width(), self.height()) 
        self.leftMouseButtonPressed = False
        self.createGui()

    def createGui(self):
        self.graphicsScene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.graphicsScene)

        # I want to replace this line with a line that sets to the actual scene size
        self.graphicsScene.setSceneRect(0,0,368,235)
        mainItem = MyQtCharIdentifierMain(self.graphicsScene.sceneRect())
        self.graphicsScene.addItem(mainItem)
        mainItem.setPos(0,0)
```

Comment: The problem is that a `QGraphicsScene` doesn't really have a size *until* you add one or more items to it.

Answer (score 2):

Getters of the dimensions of the sceneRect are
`QGraphicsScene.sceneRect()`, `QGraphicsScene.width()` and `QGraphicsScene.height()`

if the sceneRect changes, `QGraphicsScene.sceneRectChanged` -signal is emitted, sendig the new sceneRect as parameter.

If `QGraphicsView.setSceneRect()` is not set, `QGraphicsView.sceneRect()` will 
return the same value as `QGraphicsScene.sceneRect()` and it changes with `QGraphicsScene.sceneRect()`, see [documentation QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) and [documentation QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop)

Comment: If I want to get the size of the scene before inserting items to it can I get the size from the view?